# How can I find get attribute of a select tag where value = something using jquery?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

How can I get the price attribute's value where #products.option value = 6.

```
<select id="products">
<option value="2" price="60.00">Product 1</option>
<option value="4" price="40.00">Product 2</option>
<option value="6" price="40.00">Product 2</option>
<option value="8" price="40.00">Product 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the element by it's attribute and value.

```
alert($('#products option[value="6"]').attr('price'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rhf0q9nt/

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

**EDIT**

Thanks to @satpal:

Use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to store arbitary data on element.

**HTML**

```
<select id="products">
    <option value="2" data-price="60.00">Product 1</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="40.00">Product 2</option>
    <option value="6" data-price="40.00">Product 2</option>
    <option value="8" data-price="40.00">Product 2</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#products option[value="6"]').data('price');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7c7aet9w/

Comment: Recommend the use of `data-*` prefixed attribute

Comment: @user3407278 Thank Satpal also

Answer (score 1):

You can

1) use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** for getting option with value equal to 6:

2) use `.attr('price')` to get the value for above option

```
var price = $('option[value=6]').attr('price');
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4vanLwsz/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attr()` function:

```
var price = $('#products option[value=6]').attr('price');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with

```
var price = $('#products option[value="6"]').attr('price');
```